# How to display more than three views in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, list, list-view

Is there any way to display more than 3 views in OOTB SharePoint list or library.

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SP 2013 uses clienttemplates.js to create the those views control.
You can either create a JSLink or add the following script using the script Editor webpart to the page where your list view resides.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(overrideSurfacePivotCount, 'clienttemplates.js');

function overrideSurfacePivotCount() {
   ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 4;
};
</script>
```

[image]

You can find more details about the ClientPivotControl and other rendering techniques in the 'clienttemplates.debug.js'

Comment: Excellent This Works. Thank you very much, i will look more into that js.

Comment: The solution is perfect for when you want to update the number of views on specific list/library just remember you need to add the script editor to EVERY view for it to consistently show 4 views on each view.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can edit the page that contains each view (Site Actions > Edit Page) and then insert a Content Editor Web Part. Within this web part, you can add links to each of your views and format/style them as needed.

2) The property that controls the default value is hidden by the XsltListViewWebPart control, so unfortunately we can't modify it to be a value of >3.

Comment: Hello Hardik, thanks for the response. I already tried the first option, is there any other work around or way to display 4 items instead .

Comment: currently no. but still i will try to get any and will update you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Good hint about "ClientPivotControl" here, thanks!

However, inserting the above webpart script broke my CSS on list views for anonymous users so I found another workaround and thought I'd share it.

Basically, find all occurrences of variable "SurfacedPivotCount" in c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ files and change it's values from default 2 or 3 to 6 (anything more than 3).

There will be 8 files to edit:

1. clienttemplates.js
2. clienttemplates.debug.js
3. PivotControl.js
4. PivotControl.debug.js
5. search.analyticsrecommendation.js
6. search.analyticsrecommendation.debug.js
7. SP.UI.People.js
8. SP.UI.People.debug.js

for example in SP.UI.People.debug.js in the line:

```
SP.UI.People.PeopleListViewPane.get_view().$Z_0.SurfacedPivotCount = 2;
```

change the value from 2 to 6.

Comment: This works an absolute treat if your looking to increase the default number of views right across the board for all lists and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this.
1. Edit the page and add script editor and add below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 5;   
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames);
}
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
    Header: renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments
  }
});
</script>
```

2. Add the script to a JS file and refer it in your masterPage so as to apply this to all the Lists in your site.

`function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames) {
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 5;
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames);
}
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", overrideSurfacePivotCount);`

Refer below article if you need to alter it to display the views conditionally:

[How to display more than 3 views in SharePoint List](https://spshell.blogspot.com/2018/04/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in.html)