# How do I display all my document views on 1 page for a document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Since the document library only displays 3 views and then you are forced to click on an ellipsis to see the other views is it possible OOB to somehow display all the views on a separate page ?

Most of my users fail to realize that additional views are available by clicking on the ellipsis.  At minimum it would be cleaner if I could create a separate page and maybe thru a web part display all the views...

Comment: You can also check this link to get more than 3 views displayed: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114806/how-to-display-more-than-three-views-in-sharepoint-2013 or maybe you are interested to show multiple views in tabs, then you can check this: https://afrait.com/blog/multiple-tile-view-and-list-tabs-2-of-2-en/

Comment: ♦ If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get View names/links after display

On the View Page you could run a script **after** the page is displayed

```
var Views=eval(ctx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);//convert String to Array
SP.UI.Status.addStatus("This page has more Views hidden behind the <b>...</b>");
Views.forEach(function(View){//loop all Views
    console.info(View);
    var HTML=String.format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>",View.OnClickAction,View.DisplayText);
    SP.UI.Status.addStatus(HTML);
});
```

[image]

#### Change ViewSelector with CSR before display

If you use CSR (with a JSlink on the ListView webpart) you have full control over the ViewSelector **before** it is displayed:

Vadim posted it a couple of times:

- [How to display more than 3 views in document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library)
- [SharePoint 2013 Library Views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117642/sharepoint-2013-library-views/117850#117850)

  ```
  function renderHeaderTemplateWithAllViewsMenu(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
      var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
      ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = viewData.length -2; //display all View options except 'Create View' & 'Modify View'   
      return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render default Header template
  }

  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    Templates: {
      Header: renderHeaderTemplateWithAllViewsMenu
    }
  });
  ```

#### Get View Names from another Page/List

I have never used it like this to construct the URL, so I think you have to construct the URLs from the Title yourself. (there is no URL defined in the [ViewCreationInformation  Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245993.aspx))

You can get the View definitions from (another) listID with:

```
var listID=SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list=context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listID);
var views = list.get_views();
context.load(views);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
      var viewEnumerator = views.getEnumerator();
      while (viewEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var view = viewEnumerator.get_current();
        var viewinfo={
          id:view.get_id()
          ,default:view.get_defaultView()
          ,title:view.get_title()
          ,jslink:view.get_jsLink()
          ,hidden:view.get_hidden()
          ,rowLimit:view.get_rowLimit()
          ,personalview:view.get_personalView()
          ,baseviewId:view.get_baseViewId()
          ,viewData:view.get_viewData()
          ,viewFields:view.get_viewFields()
          ,viewQury:view.get_viewQuery()
        }
        console.info(viewinfo);
      }          
    }, 
    function(){console.error(arguments);}
);
```

iView

Answer (score 2):

Each view has a unique URL like /AllItems.aspx, /view1.aspx and so on, right? So if your views count is more than 3, but stable, what you can do is create a page with simple HTML content and manually put links to all views maybe adding some description. Wiki page will work even better

Comment: Thats what I initially started to do, but I wanted something more dynamic..If I get hit by a bus then the list will never get updated...but per your comment if I think the the views will be stable it is a possibility..why a Wiki page and not a reg. page

Comment: Wiki is just easier to set up with all that '[[ |' syntax. Solutions up above are dynamic. I'd implement this one - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library . Given modern monitors' width it seems logical to show all views in a row . PS. Please don't get hit by a bus :)

Answer (score 2):

Create an HTML Page and add the following Javascript. The following JS will fetch all the views on click of the button. You can modify it accordingly.

```
<script language="ecmascript" type="text/ecmascript">
       var web = null;
        var listCollection =null;
        var list = null;
        var viewCollection =null;

       function getViews() {
            var clientContext =new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                this.web = clientContext.get_web();
                this.listCollection = web.get_lists();
                this.list = listCollection.getByTitle("Documents");
                this.viewCollection = list.get_views();
                clientContext.load(this.viewCollection);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
            }
        }

       function onQuerySucceeded() {
            var viewName ='Views: \n';
            var viewsEnumerator =this.viewCollection.getEnumerator();
            while (viewsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var view = viewsEnumerator.get_current();
                viewName += view.get_title() + '\n';
            }
            alert(viewName);
        }

       function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }</script>
    <input id="btnGetViews" onclick="getViews()" type="button" value="Get All Views" />
```

Source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/get-all-the-views-for-a-particular-list-in-sharepoint-2010-u/

Comment: So does this get views for the Documents library per your code above...

Comment: Yes. It gets the views