# Missing "What's hot" link in discussion board list in SharePoint Online

Tags: office-365, discussion-board

I have team site in Office 365. I have created a discussion board list. The issue is it is not displaying all the filters like "What's hot". Please see below image for more details:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this OOB? Am I missing any configurations?

Update --

Need to enable rating settings in the list settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate community site feature in a team site to get all Discussion board features and it will create a Discussion board app with activating. It comes with all your expected features.

But the Discussion board app that you added to team site is not giving all features.

1. Go to site settings.
2. Click "Manage Site Features"
3. Activate "Community Site Feature".

[image]

Comment: When I activated the feature, SharePoint created new discussion list, which has this view. But my old discussion list is same. Even I tried creating new discussion board, but I am getting the same view.

Comment: The discussion board app we added separately doesn`t come with all feature as OOB. You can compare the list settings and fields also.

Comment: One more issue even with OOB list added, if I put it as listviewwebpart on any other page, the reply and what's hot is removed.

Comment: Yes, you were right. settings were different for my created discussion board. Updated question with answer.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint by default only displays 3 of the N Views in the ViewSelector

You have to add some JavaScript code to the page to change that ViewSelector

See:
[How do I display all my document views on 1 page for a document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171642/how-do-i-display-all-my-document-views-on-1-page-for-a-document-library)
and all references from the last answer